# How to generate relative risk from a glmer model?

Tags: r

I am trying to generate relative risk from a glmer model, using the following code:

```
myModelSummary <- function(modelResult,npar=TRUE,print=TRUE)
     { Mt<-coef(summary(modelResult))[,1]
      RRt<-exp(Mt)
      lowert<-exp(Mt +qnorm(.025)*coef(summary(modelResult))[,2])
      Uppert<-exp(Mt +qnorm(.975)*coef(summary(modelResult))[,2])
      allSS<-cbind(RRt, lowert, Uppert, pvalue=coef(summary(modelResult))[,4])
      print(allSS)}
```

However, the output of the above code is confusing to me. It may be because I am not familiar with R. Please llet me know if you need more info on the data or the model code.

```
                             RRt     lowert        Uppert   pvalue
(Intercept)            3.494119e+18 0.00000000    Inf    0.993365605
Water.movementslo      1.013757e+00 0.00000000    Inf    0.999998219
Water.movementfas      8.945607e-01 0.00000000    Inf    0.999985479
Habitat.depthw100      4.000983e-18 0.00000000    Inf    0.995010681
Habitat.size.m2.       9.960273e-01 0.98701660 1.0051202 0.390609564
```